# C# is not able to convert my Character to String in a Foreach loop

Tags: c#, json, string

I am using a simple code to read the JSON data. I previously needed some help in that, but I am able to overcome the exception through a Google search about the error. But this time, there is no exception instead it is an un-understandable statement.

The statement is,

> Unable to convert 'char' to 'string'.

I do understand that there was a trouble while casting the character data type to a string data type. But I never used any Character sequence in my code at all.

Here is the code I am using,

```
Stream fs = File.Open(new MainWindow().getFileName("events"), FileMode.Open);
if (fs.Length != 0)
{
    // File is not empty!
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(fs);
    // Get each event
    foreach (string events in jsonObject["allEvents"].ToString()) {
        /* here is the error */
    }
}
```

I am getting the array, from the JSON file. And converting it into a String, but it keeps telling me I can't. The file content is as

```
{  
    "allEvents":  [  
         {  
             "eventId": 1,  
             "eventType":  "birthday"  
         },  
         {  
             "eventId": 2,  
             "eventType": "meeting"  
         }  
    ]  
}
```

Right now, I really don't know what is wrong and how is wrong. But I can't get it to work. Please guide me!

Snapshot for the error: It is compile time error, not a runtime (After adding the code from Jon Skeet)

[image]

Comment: I think the error message is very clear for your error.

Comment: I have tried that too. That didn't work.

Comment: You have an array of JSON objects, not strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `foreach` *on* a string. Effectively:

```
string x = "foo";
foreach (string y in x)
```

That makes no sense - a `string` is a sequence of *characters*, not a sequence of *strings*. In order to get the code to compile, you *could* just remove the `ToString` call:

```
foreach (string eventItem in jsonObject["allEvents"])
{
    ...
}
```

That will let it *compile*, but then each item isn't a string - it's an object. In fact, we need to use our knowledge that `allEvents` is an array. (This API is somewhat poorly designed, IMO...)

```
JsonArray array = (JsonArray) jsonObject["allEvents"];
foreach (JsonValue eventItem in array)
{
    int id = (int) eventItem["eventId"];
    string type = (string) eventItem["eventType"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing that you told! It gives me a lengthy name for that, cannot convert from `system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair` to `string`. Due to that I tried to explicitly, convert it to string. But that didn't work either!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Do you mean the first snippet or the second? The first snippet explains why the code doesn't compile - but the second snippet is what you actually need.

Comment: Second code snippet! It is still giving me error, of not being able to convert it to, System.Json.JsonValue. **Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Json.JsonValue>' to 'System.Json.JsonValue'**

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Is this in Silverlight? I'm trying to reproduce the problem. (It doesn't help that we don't know *where* you're seeing that error - or whether it's at compile-time or execution time.)

Comment: I created the Application for XAML/C#, just included the System.Json project. Application Project **isn't** a Silverlight project. Just a NuGet addition for the System.Json package. :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Do you mean the [`System.Json`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json) package which has now been removed? Any reason you don't want to use Json.NET?

Comment: I have included a snapshot for the error, and yes, it is a compile time error not a runtime.

Comment: one reason, that I never knew there is such package, named Json.NET!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Okay, I've now reproduced it and fixed it - see the code in my edit, which works with your sample data. I would definitely recommend using Json.NET instead of a now-removed Nuget package...

Comment: thanks alot! :) But I meant, thanks for the advice. I would now move forward to the Json.NET package! :)